# error in SQL syntax MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CompletedNo SELECT (OrderNo.) FROM `order` WHERE `OrderNo.`

Tags: php, sql, database, syntax-error, transfer

The following php script is used to retrieve set of data(OrderNo.) from a database! when the delete link is clicked i want to remove the row in which that specific delete link exists and transfer the data to the 'transfer' table!

```
<?php
                require("includes/db.php");

                $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ";
                $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    echo"<head>";
    echo'
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="view.css">
                <head>


            ';
    echo"</head>";

    echo "<body >";
    echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 > " ;
    echo"<tr bgcolor=grey>";
    echo"<td align=center>";
    echo "<font size=4>";
    echo "<B>";
    echo "Order No.";
    echo "</B>";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"</tr>";


    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        echo"<tr>";
         echo"<td align=center>";
        echo $row["OrderNo."];
         echo "<br>";
         echo"</td>";
       echo "<td align=center>";
    echo "<a href='delete.php?del=";
    echo $row['OrderNo.'];
    echo "'>delete</a>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
        echo"</table>";

?>
```

The following php script is executed when a delete link  is clicked! when only the query for the delete function was executed it worked but after insertion of another query to transfer the values to 'transfer' table was written a syntax 
error occured.

```
<?php
     include("includes/db.php");

    if( isset($_GET['del']) )
    {
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        $sql1="INSERT INTO transfer CompletedNo SELECT (OrderNo.) FROM `order` WHERE `OrderNo.` = '$id' ";
        $res1= mysqli_query($db,$sql1) or die("Failed".mysqli_error($db));
        $sql2= "DELETE FROM `order` WHERE `OrderNo.` = '$id' ";
        $res2= mysqli_query($db,$sql2) or die("Failed".mysqli_error($db));

    }
?>
```

please help me to correct it the error is only on line

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO transfer CompletedNo SELECT (OrderNo.) FROM `order` WHERE `OrderNo.` = '$id' ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Parenthesis` around the `Insert` column list

```sql
INSERT INTO transfer (CompletedNo) 
SELECT `OrderNo.` FROM `order` WHERE `OrderNo.` = '$id'
```